# ¿Como llenar un mi recyclerview con picasso en un fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, picasso, android-recyclerview

*Este es mi adapter:*

```
public class AdapterMarcas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMarcas.ViewHolderMarcas> {

List<Marcas> listMarcas  = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public AdapterMarcas(Context  context, ArrayList<Marcas> listMarcas) {
    this.listMarcas = listMarcas;
    this.context = context;

}


public class ViewHolderMarcas extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgV;

    public ViewHolderMarcas(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgV = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolderMarcas onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_marcas, parent, false);
    ViewHolderMarcas viewHolderMarcas = new ViewHolderMarcas(view);
    return viewHolderMarcas;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderMarcas holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(listMarcas.get(position).getImagen()).into(holder.imgV);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listMarcas.size();
}
```

*Esta es mi clase o pojo:*

```
public class Marcas {
private String nombre;
private String imagen;

public Marcas() {
}

public Marcas(String nombre, String imagen) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.imagen = imagen;

}


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
```

*Este es mi fragment - Aqui es donde tengo duda de como mandar a llamar mi los elementos de mi web service con picasso *

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment{

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
ArrayList<Marcas> listMarcas;
AdapterMarcas adapterMarcas;
ProgressDialog dialog;
public InicioFragment() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    listMarcas = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context = getActivity();
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapterMarcas);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    return view;
}
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: donde tienes las imágenes?

Comment: Las tengo en una carpeta donde esta mi web service y en mi base de datos tengo la ruta de las imagenes

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia ya que no indicas detalles de como consultas ese WS para obtener el listado de imagenes. En realidad primeramente debes servir de alguna forma las imagenes.

Comment: Perdón si no fui muy claro amigo, quiero saber como obtener el listado en el fragment, ya que lo único que tengo es la conexión a mi web service, tengo el adapter, tengo el pojo o mi clase objeto con setter y getter

Comment: Es dificil determinar como obtener las imagenes ya que desconocemos como consultar el WS que tienes para obtener las imagenes, esto es lo más importante en la pregunta, tienes un WSDL o la url para consultar, que parámetros recibe? @Diego

Comment: Lo quiero como https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37s1Z8VQW2E pero en vez de usar volley usar picasso